# Union with different columns

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have table A with a column called product and table B without the column "product". is there a way to combine null rows from table B with not null rows from table A?

```
SELECT SEGMENT, COUNTRY, PRODUCT, SUM([UNIT SOLD]) AS "UNITS SOLD", 
0 AS "MANUFACTURING PRICE", 0 AS "SALES_PRICE"
FROM TABLE A
            
UNION OR UNION ALL 
            
SELECT SEGMENT, COUNTRY, NULL AS PRODUCT, 0 AS "UNITS SOLD", 
SUM([MANUFACTURING PRICE]) AS "MANFAC PRICE", SUM([SALES PRICE]) AS "SALES PRICE"
FROM TABLE A
```

[image]

```
UNION (Final Table) 
                
|Segment    |Country    |Product    |Units Sold |Man Price  |Sale Price |  Total 
|:----------|:----------|:----------|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:
|Government |Canada     |Carretera  |1618.5     |$5.00      |$15.00     |$24,277.50
|Government |Germany    |Carretera  |1321       |$10.00     |$20.00     |$26,420.00
|Midmarket  |France     |Montana    |2178       |$10.00     |$15.00     |$32,670.00
|Midmarket  |Germany    |Montana    |888        |$10.00     |$12.00     |$10,656.00
|Midmarket  |Mexico     |Paseo      |2470       |$10.00     |$350.00    |$864,500.00
```

Comment: Is there only ever 1 `Product` in each `Segment` and `Country` combination?

Comment: You have included some typos when you transposed the queries, please check that your individual queries return the correct results and consider posting a fiddle so we can assist you better

Comment: no there is more than one product and that is the problem. I will repost it.

Comment: If there is more than 1 product, then it doesn't really make sense to merge the two tables as you have suggested, you wouldn't want to base this join on ordinal position, wouldn't manufacturing and sale price be dependant on the specific product, we can't just arbitrarily link the rows, there needs to be a specific criteria

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `UNION` what you probably want here is a `JOIN`. Union  will result in the records from each table being added together to create a single list, so 5 + 5 source rows will be 10 rows in the output.

A `JOIN` however will match rows from the two record sets together which will allow you to `COALESCE` the values between the two sets. The number of rows will be the total number of unique matches.

- In this case we *could* match on `Segement` and `Country` and it will produce the expected results for this dataset, but this will only work if there is only a single `Product` for each set of `Segement` and `Country` which in many domains would not make much sense.

When we look closer at the queries, both the source tables are actually aggregates and the null values have been manufactured, so we don't need a `COALESCE` at all for this example we simply specify which table we want to source the result field from.

*I have used inline table expressions for this, your RDBMS version may support CTEs which might improve the readability of this query*

```
SELECT 
     TA.SEGMENT, TA.COUNTRY, TA.PRODUCT, TA.UNITS_SOLD, 
     TB.MANUFACTURING_PRICE, TB.UNIT_PRICE
FROM (
    SELECT SEGMENT, COUNTRY, PRODUCT, SUM([UNIT SOLD]) AS UNITS_SOLD 
    FROM TABLE A
    GROUP BY SEGMENT, COUNTRY, PRODUCT
) TA
JOIN (            
    SELECT SEGMENT, COUNTRY, SUM([MANUFACTURING PRICE]) AS MANFACTURING_PRICE, SUM([SALES PRICE]) AS SALES_PRICE
    FROM TABLE B
    GROUP BY SEGMENT, COUNTRY
) TB ON TA.SEGMENT = TB.SEGMENT AND TA.COUNTRY = TB.COUNTRY
```

Comment: Seems like the aggregates only work for the units sold. As far as sales price, if I sell some units for $5.00 each now and later some more for $6.00 each, the total sale price is not $11.00, same for manufacturing price. and average doesn't work either. The best you can do with the data we have is use Table A as a master table. but it really will depend on the real requirements of the OP.

Comment: As this question is tagged db2-400, instead of using `[ ]` around field names with spaces you need `" "`, and yes, DB2 for i supports CTEs.

Comment: I have about 7 diff columns and columns have lots of diff values that will requires me at least 7 joins to get the final result you mentioned. That is why I was thinking about union.

Comment: You might get more value out of posting the actual query, or at least something a bit closer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Is not this sufficient ?

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.SEGMENT, T2.SEGMENT) AS SEGMENT,
       COALESCE(T1.COUNTRY, T2.COUNTRY) AS COUNTRY,
       T1.PRODUCT, 
       SUM(T1."UNIT SOLD") AS "UNITS SOLD",
       SUM(T2."MANUFACTURING PRICE") AS "MANFAC PRICE", 
       SUM(T2."SALES PRICE") AS "SALES PRICE",
       SUM(T1."UNIT SOLD") * SUM(T2."SALES PRICE") AS TOTAL
FROM   TABLE_A AS T1
       FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_A AS T2
          ON T1.T1.SEGMENT = T2.T1.SEGMENT
          AND T1.COUNTRY = T2.COUNTRY
GROUP  BY COALESCE(T1.SEGMENT, T2.SEGMENT),
          COALESCE(T1.COUNTRY, T2.COUNTRY),
          T1.PRODUCT;
```

Comment: so the reason I did not do join was because I must have more than 2 join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

SQL `UNION` add rows to your result, so the only way to achieve what you want is to `group by` your results.

```
select
    combined.SEGMENT,
    combined.COUNTRY,
    max(combined.PRODUCT) as PRODUCT,
    max(combined.[UNITS SOLD]) as UNITS_SOLD,
    max(combined.[MANUFACTURING PRICE]) as MANUFACTURING_PRICE,
    max(combined.SALES_PRICE) as SALES_PRICE
from
    (
        SELECT
            SEGMENT, COUNTRY, PRODUCT, SUM([UNIT SOLD]) AS "UNITS SOLD",
            0 AS "MANUFACTURING PRICE", 0 AS "SALES_PRICE"
        FROM A
        group by SEGMENT, COUNTRY, PRODUCT

    UNION

        SELECT SEGMENT, COUNTRY, NULL AS PRODUCT, 0 AS "UNITS SOLD",
            SUM([MANUFACTURING PRICE]) AS "MANFAC PRICE", SUM([SALES PRICE]) AS "SALES PRICE"
        FROM B
        group by SEGMENT, COUNTRY 
) as combined

group by
combined.SEGMENT,
combined.COUNTRY
```

**example result**

| SEGMENT | COUNTRY | PRODUCT | UNITSD | PRICE | SALES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Government | Carretera | Carretera | 1618 | 15 | 24000 |
| Government | Germany | Carretera | 1321 | 10 | 26420 |